# Surface Integrals - Normal Vector

Tags: calculus

I'm currently writing the course material for my own Multivariable Calculus Course, and I've hit a slight bump along the way.

Suppose that we have a surface, $S$, defined parametrically
$$
\vec{r}(u,v)=x(u,v)\vec{i}+y(u,v)\vec{j}+z(u,v)\vec{k}
$$
As we know, we can find two 'tangent vectors', say $\vec{r}_u$ and $\vec{r}_v$, where $\vec{r}_u=\frac{d\vec{r}}{du} $ and $\vec{r}_v=\frac{d\vec{r}}{dv} $. By assuming that these two vectors are somewhat in the direction of $u$ and $v$ respectively, is it correct to also assume that they are parallel, i.e $$\vec{r}_u\cdot \vec{r}_v=0$$
Recall that the (unit) normal vector $\vec{n}$ is the cross product of these two vectors (divided by the length if you're considering a unit vector). Based on this assumption (after looking at the formula), justify whether the assumption $$\vec{r}_u\cdot \vec{r}_v=0$$ is true or not??
Thanks guys!

Also, $a\cdot b=|a||b|\cos\theta$, not $a\cdot b=|a||b|\sin\theta$ as I said in the comments - woops! Mistakes are easily made.

Comment: isn't it when two vectors are perpendicular that their dot product is zero? and if their dot product is 1 they're parallel?

Comment: I just read my notes on this stuff and one point they make is that $\bf T_u$ and $\bf T_v$ need not be orthogonal as they change with position $(x,y,z)$

Comment: @SamuelFeinberg Careful: $\vec a \cdot \vec b := |a||b| \color{red}{\cos} \theta$.

Comment: Actually, $\vec r_u, \vec r_v$ might not be orthogonal, which depends on the choice of your $u,v$. Even for a plane, these vectors can be "not-perpendicular". Take $z =0$ as an example.

Comment: My mistake, it's $\cos \theta$ rather than $\sin \theta$, but if you think about it geometrically (I may be completely wrong) but if you consider $\vec{n}$, it's pointing perpendicular to the respective point on $S$, but I've seen people assuming that the two vectors which I've listed are parallel. So far it's the only thing I'm unsure about.